# Pycharm 2019 not showing print() output; yet exit code 0. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10

**helloWorld.py**

```
print('hello world')
print("i love all you people")
```

**My Run results in PyCharm:**

```
C:\Python37\python3.exe C:/Users/kolose49/PycharmProjects/myFirstProgram/helloWorld.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**My results in IDLE (Python 3.7.2 Shell)**

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
== RESTART: C:\Users\kolose49\PycharmProjects\myFirstProgram\helloWorld.py ==
hello world
i love all you people
>>>
```

**Project Interpreter**

```
Settings>Project: myFirstProgram>Project Interpreter>Python 3.7 C:\Python37\python3.exe
```

**Structure:**

In folder *myFirstProgram*

- venv

  - Include
  - Lib

    - site-packages
  - Scripts

    - activate
    - activate.bat
    - Activate.ps1
    - deactivte.bat
    - python.exe
    - pythonw.exe
  - pyvenv.cfg
- helloWorld.py

Note: Even when it's one print() line, no output is shown.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question ?

Comment: Can I have your complete code of helloWorld.py for reference ?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Just in case someone else experiences the same issue.

A third-party app `COMODO Firewall` kept blocking the PyCharm processes; which wasn't obvious because PyCharm was online and could update plugins, repositories etc.

I went to `COMODO Firewall`, clicked on `Blocked Applications`, selected the PyCharm items and clicked `Unblock > Unblock for all security components`.

So if your code runs just fine but with no output in a given application, consider checking quarantining software like `Firewall apps`, `Security apps` etc.

Cheers!